# Permanent session storage in Node

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, angularjs, express

I have a node server running right now, I use `npm forever` to keep it running when I'm not developing and I use `npm nodemon` for when I edit (restarts app on edit/upload).

I noticed that whenever I restart my app, session data is lost and my players have to re-login to their accounts. It's not a huuuge deal, but I was wondering if there was a way to edit my server.js page without restarting the app, and logging everybody out?

(Note that this only applies for server.js or module edits. `.html` and `.js` pages that are served don't require a restart)

(Second note: I am using mysql, nodejs, angularjs, express.io for all this, just in case anybody asks)

Comment: I use node-cluster API, and restart workers by one without main process restarting... But also I've not any important data in it's memory, there is Redis for this... mysql is not best place for sessions, add some like Redis (or Memcache) for this to your stack..

Comment: check (your portfolio) {return "You are making game"}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't a way to edit a file (and have the changes loaded) without rebooting the server and reloading the file.  Instead, store your session data somewhere other than memory.  I know you're using MySQL, so use the [connect-mysql](https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect-mysql) package (there are other packages like this for redis, MongoDB, etc).

It's as simple as putting this in your `app.js` file:

```
var MySQLStore = require('connect-mysql')(express)
    ,  options = {
      config: {
        host : 'place.stuff',
        user: 'RUJordan',
        password: 'hunter2',
        database: 'SomeKittensIsGreat'
      }
  };

app.use(express.session({
    secret: 'UpvoteThisAnswer',
    store: new MySQLStore(options),
    cookie: { maxAge: 2592000000 } // 30 days
}));
```

This will place a HTTP-only (i.e. the user can't see/use it) cookie on each user's computer.  Even after a server reboot, `connect-mysql` will be able to like a user with their session data in MySQL via this cookie.

Comment: @Seth yes, he knows this because he's helped me before and we're both [JS Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript-is-for-lovers) regulars.

Comment: @Seth Yes, I've helped him with this before.

Comment: wouldn't going through the network, a db, a file, then a network again be a lot slower than pulling from ram?

Comment: @dandavis The network (the slowest part of that, exponentially) will be used regardless of session store technology.  While I haven't run any benchmarks, the load added here should be negligible.